# How to design a circuit that works on both negedge and posedge

Tags: verilog

I have a clock phase bit which decides on which clock edge the design must work. I cannot use an always block inside an if statement. Is it possible to use

```
`ifdef
```

statement? will the **`ifdef** be synthesizable?

Thanks

Comment: You just need to selectively invert the clock before you send it to the rest of your logic.

Comment: I have a control register CR and based on the value of the CR,  'always @(posedge)'   in case CR is 1 or  'always negedge)'   in case CR is 0 will be activated. How do I use a control statement like an if to select the correct clocking block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this.

One way is to selectively invert the clock before you use it in your logic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHq6mA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With this approach, if `Clock edge select` is 0, then the polarity of the external and internal clock is the same, and the logic operates on the rising edge of the external clock. On the other hand, if `clock edge select` is 1, the internal clock is inverted with respect to the external clock, and the logic operates on the falling edge of the external clock, which corresponds to the rising edge of the internal clock.

The other way is to simply implement both blocks and then select the correct output(s):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsVe9e.png)</sup>

This uses more resources, but has the advantage that U1 and U2 can implement slightly different logic, if necessary. Both blocks are active all the time, but you simply discard the outputs from the "wrong" one.

Answer (score 0):

`ifdef is part of the preprocessor, so it is evaluated before synthesis.  So long as the resulting code is synthesizable, you should be fine.